# How to pass a variable to Scrapy Spider

Tags: python, scrapy

I have a list in spider class. I need to initialize it. This is what code looks like:

```
class Myspider(SitemapSpider):
    name = 'spidername'

    sitemap_urls = [
                    'https://www.arabam.com/sitemap/otomobil_13.xml']
sitemap_rules = [
    ('/otomobil/', 'parse'),

]
custom_settings = {'FEED_FORMAT':'csv','FEED_URI': "arabam_"+str(datetime.today().strftime('%d%m%y'))+'.csv'
                   }
crawled = []
new_links = 0
def parse(self,response):
    if self.new_links >3:
        with open("URLs", "wb") as f:

                pickle.dump(self.crawled, f)
        self.new_links = 0
    for td in response.xpath("/html/body/div[3]/div[6]/div[4]/div/div[2]/table/tbody/tr/td[4]/div/a"):

        if link[0] not in self.crawled:

            self.crawled.append(link[0])
```

#################################some code

```
process = CrawlerProcess({
})
Myspider.crawled = []
Myspider.crawled.append("hi")
try:
        with (open("URLs", "rb")) as openfile:
            while True:
                try:
                    Myspider.crawled = pickle.load(openfile)

                except EOFError:
                    break
except:
        with open("URLs", "wb") as f:
            pickle.dump("", f)
print(Myspider.crawled)
process.crawl(Myspider, Myspider.crawled)
process.start() # the script wi
```

It keeps throwing following exception:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:\Users\fatima.arshad\AppData\Local\Continuum\anaconda2\envs\web_scraping\lib\site-packages\twisted\internet\defer.py", line 151, in maybeDeferred
    result = f(*args, **kw)
  File "C:\Users\fatima.arshad\AppData\Local\Continuum\anaconda2\envs\web_scraping\lib\site-packages\pydispatch\robustapply.py", line 55, in robustApply
    return receiver(*arguments, **named)
  File "C:\Users\fatima.arshad\AppData\Local\Continuum\anaconda2\envs\web_scraping\lib\site-packages\scrapy\extensions\feedexport.py", line 262, in item_scraped
    slot = self.slot
AttributeError: 'FeedExporter' object has no attribute 'slot'
```

According to some resource it is because of this:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:\Users\fatima.arshad\AppData\Local\Continuum\anaconda2\envs\web_scraping\lib\site-packages\twisted\internet\defer.py", line 151, in maybeDeferred
    result = f(*args, **kw)
  File "C:\Users\fatima.arshad\AppData\Local\Continuum\anaconda2\envs\web_scraping\lib\site-packages\pydispatch\robustapply.py", line 55, in robustApply
    return receiver(*arguments, **named)
  File "C:\Users\fatima.arshad\AppData\Local\Continuum\anaconda2\envs\web_scraping\lib\site-packages\scrapy\extensions\feedexport.py", line 232, in open_spider
    uri = self.urifmt % self._get_uri_params(spider)
  File "C:\Users\fatima.arshad\AppData\Local\Continuum\anaconda2\envs\web_scraping\lib\site-packages\scrapy\extensions\feedexport.py", line 313, in _get_uri_params
    params[k] = getattr(spider, k)
  File "C:\Users\fatima.arshad\AppData\Local\Continuum\anaconda2\envs\web_scraping\lib\site-packages\scrapy\spiders\__init__.py", line 36, in logger
    logger = logging.getLogger(self.name)
  File "C:\Users\fatima.arshad\AppData\Local\Continuum\anaconda2\envs\web_scraping\lib\logging\__init__.py", line 1845, in getLogger
    return Logger.manager.getLogger(name)
  File "C:\Users\fatima.arshad\AppData\Local\Continuum\anaconda2\envs\web_scraping\lib\logging\__init__.py", line 1174, in getLogger
    raise TypeError('A logger name must be a string')
TypeError: A logger name must be a string
```

How do I pass it the list or there is any way that this list canbe initialized only once with scrapy spider?
List contains all the urls that have been crawled. This list is pickled. When the code starts, it initializes this list and crawls further only if the link is not present in this list.

Answer (score 0):

You need to pass the list of urls using the spider attribute name (which is `crawled`) in your case.

According to the [docs](https://docs.scrapy.org/en/latest/topics/spiders.html#spider-arguments), if you don't override the `__init__` method of the spider, all the passed arguments to the spider class are mapped to the spider attributes. So in order to override the `crawled` attribute, you need to send the extact argument name.

Something like this:

```
process = CrawlerProcess()
crawled_urls = []

try:
    with (open("URLs", "rb")) as openfile:
        while True:
            try:
                crawled_urls = pickle.load(openfile)

            except EOFError:
                break
except:
    with open("URLs", "wb") as f:
        pickle.dump("", f)

print(crawled_urls)
process.crawl(Myspider, crawled=crawled_urls)
process.start() # the script wi
```